# Calling Python CLI program from django views and displaying the results back asynchronously?

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, django-views, celery

I have a django project having a web interface where you can upload files and after the upload is successful it calls the cli version of the software to process it and returns the result after it's successful execution

Here, is a bit of snippet I use in my `views.py`

```
from cliproject.main import clirunner
# Some code for file upload and saving
clirunner()
```

This will run the command line python script `main.py` which is present inside `cliproject/` directory and it will do some stuff and saves the output

The problem is, this whole process is Synchronous at this moment. Hence, the user page loads after they upload the file from the UI and until it gets processed by Python CLI script behind the scenes.
The flow is as

```
Django UI
   | (User upload files)
views.py gets request and saves it somewhere
   | (views run clirunner() to give python cli program control)
cliproject runs
   | (After doing the stuff which is intended, it saves the output file)
views.py resumes
   | (Reads the output file)
Django UI displays the output file
```

So, we can see the problem here that I am calling a different CLI program from views.py to do the stuff which I want. But it happens synchronously.

What I need is to make the process Asynchronous and I want to show something as a Loading Bar to notify them that the cli program is executing at the back-side and it's status.
After CLI program is done executing then loading bar will reach 100% and asynchronously django UI will display the output

I tried Celery. But I could not figure out how to make this loading bar work based on the python cli script. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have a thought, you need:

A) To launch the task asynchronously

B) To be able to get the value of its current status.

Here's an idea:

1) Make the task a manage.py command that you can invoke using threads or have a Celery task call.

2) As the task executes, have it write its current completion state using a Django model to your DB of choice. (The step above is meant to simplify using the DB. You can always write directly if you need to do so.)

3) Pass the task id (assigned by you or generated by Celery, on a db column that's indexed) to the template context and use an AJAX call to ping a view that returns the percentage complete from a database lookup, then set your completion from there.

This way, your view submits and launches the task, it takes care of marking its own work, and then the other view just makes a quick db query to find out where it is.

Edited to add: You could also use the `cache` backend and write to a key in something like memcached, redis, etc. to avoid pings on your relational database.

Comment: Yes, those two things are what I need. The problem is, I have no idea how fast the task will get executed or not. It depends on the file. I can't predict when it will finish. So, how can we track it's state then?

Comment: Or to simply the process, I can also display a screw logo running to denote the user that their file is being processed without giving exact loading bar value. In that case, I can direct update once the task is finished to the user. Do you think, that can work